# Is there any file manager that tiles images with a best-fit UI like Google Image Search?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, filemanager

Linux is all about customizability, so I figure asking for help with this is fair game.

Comment: What linux distro are you running ?

Comment: stock ubuntu. Minimum character requirement for this comment stinks.

Answer (score 1):

**PCManFM** has an additional folder view mode called "Thumbnail View" for the best-fit image browsing. The best-fit varies by the image file size (dimension) and zoom level that is currently used.

[image: PCManFM GTK+ interface on Xfce]

In the menubar, go to **View > Folder View Mode (Qt variant: View) > Thumbnail View**.

To make this mode as default, go to **Edit > Preferences > General - Default View - View Mode (Qt variant: Behavior - Browsing - Default view mode)** and change from "Icon View" to "Thumbnail View".

For Ubuntu or GTK+ desktop environment, install `pcmanfm`. Else for KDE or Qt desktop environment, install `pcmanfm-qt` (16.04+). Both PCManFM variants are [available in the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pcmanfm&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).